# Waiting for webworker to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webworker that does certain things in the background. After it is done , an event is triggered by it. I want pause the execution of my program till i get that event fired. In short i need to wait for that event to occur and after it is fired i need to resume the rest of my functionality. I been searching all over the internet and i couldn't find a suitable solution for this.

```
var worker = new Worker( workInBackground );
var workInBackground = function () {

//some stuff

$(document).trigger("done")
}
```

I need to pause for "done" to be fired and then  continue my call-stack. I would really appreciate some help here

Comment: Your code would be alright if `some stuff` is synchronous code, but if it's asynchronous, like Ajax, you will need to set that as a callback. Is that your case? Without knowing what you're doing in between, it's hard to write an answer.

Comment: @blex Its asynchronous. Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it

Comment: Ok, if you still don't know what to do, what asynchronous code is running? Something like a `setTimeout`, `$.ajax()` ? The "done" event should be triggered from them (as a callback), not outside.

Comment: The solution depends on what //some stuff does. You need to publish the remainder of the code if you want more specific help.

Answer (score -1):

Just a timer, checking for a variable.

```
    var checkWorkDone = false;
    var workController = setInterval(function(){ CheckWork() }, 200);

    function CheckWork() {
        console.log("checkWorkDone = " + checkWorkDone );
        if(checkWorkDone == true)
        {
            goOnToDoNextJob();
        }
    }

    // when checkWorkDone == true, the work is done, so stop workController;
    function goOnToDoNextJob() {
        clearInterval(workController);
    }

    // this is just for checking, set var work done after 5 sec
    var testWorker = setInterval(function(){ DoJob() }, 5000);
    function DoJob()
    {
        checkWorkDone = true;
        clearInterval(testWorker);
    }
```